# How do I prevent HTML from ignoring the newline that comes from JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'd like to write my own hackertyper site that prints itself when pressing some keys.

But when I try the code below, it prints everything at the same line. I used template literals ``` (``) ``` and couldn't make it. Then tried `<br />` in the string but also not worked. How do I make it right?

Edit: I was using `<p>` tag in the HTML file, when I changed it to `<pre>` tag as Praveen said, it solved my problem. Thank you.

```js
"use strict";

let str = `"use strict"

let str = "";

let emptyStr = "";
let i = 0;
document.addEventListener("keydown", function () {
  emptyStr += str.charAt(i++) + str.charAt(i++) + str.charAt(i++);
  document.querySelector("#string").textContent = emptyStr;
});`;

let emptyStr = "";
let i = 0;
document.addEventListener("keydown", function () {
  emptyStr += str.charAt(i++) + str.charAt(i++) + str.charAt(i++);
  document.querySelector("#string").textContent = emptyStr;
});
```

```html
<p id="string"></p>
```

Comment: Can you create a proper snippet? I can help you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess if you're trying to print it out, you need to print it out on a `<pre>` tag or an element with style `white-space: pre` or similar.

**Here's an example with `<pre>` tag:**

```js
let str = `This is HackerTyper

See I have   spaces and lines!`;

let emptyStr = "";

let i = 0;
document.addEventListener("keydown", function () {
  emptyStr += str.charAt(i++) + str.charAt(i++) + str.charAt(i++);
  document.querySelector("#string").textContent = emptyStr;
});
```

```html
<pre id="string"></pre>
```

**Here's the same with `white-space: pre` for `<div>`:**

```js
let str = `This is HackerTyper

See I have   spaces and lines!`;

let emptyStr = "";

let i = 0;
document.addEventListener("keydown", function () {
  emptyStr += str.charAt(i++) + str.charAt(i++) + str.charAt(i++);
  document.querySelector("#string").textContent = emptyStr;
});
```

```css
div {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div id="string"></div>
```

And, finally, just wanted to tell, this is a really good implementation of HackerTyper.